# Doing background process even if app is terminated

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to check the time even if the app is terminated. I have read about Background modes but I don't quite understand it. Can someone give me steps?

Comment: Background modes are special modes for apps with specific features (updates of location, audio, background downloads...). It depends of your needs. Please do some basic research before posting a question (plenty of ressources online).

Answer (score 0):

Apple has restrictions in place for the use of background operations in an effort to improve user experience and extend battery life. Your app is only allowed to keep running in the background in very specific cases. For example, these include playing audio, getting location updates, or fetching the latest content from a server.

If your task does not fall into these categories backgrounding may not be for you. You may even find yourself with an App Store rejection if you try to cheat the system by using background modes outside the realm of their purposes, so consider yourself warned!

More Info:

- https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Hi @Mamunur, I have read those info. I just want to tell you what I really want to achieve and if it's possible and how.

I have a function that needs to be called for a specific time (e.g. 8 pm) whether the app is in foreground, background or terminated. For foreground and background, I know it's quite possible but I'm not sure for the terminated.